# Postgres Replication to a databse with extra colums

Tags: database, postgresql, replication

Building out a new app, and we are trying VERY hard to keep application required data from metrics and additional meta info (ie login history).

One random idea was to replicate the main db to another database that has the exact tables from the app PLUS all the additional extra meta tables (no additional columns would be added to the app data for sanity).

Is this possible?  Is this sane?
Are  there better alternatives to keeping this essential-app from non-essential data info?

Comment: You might want to look in to slony - that'll let you use higher level business logic to distribute data (as opposed to low level replication, which is an all encompassing copy) and is OK with there being extra tables in your target.

Comment: I think questions about replication are better suited at dba.SE.

Comment: Is replication of non-essential data the issue you are trying to solve, or is the separation of data? If the latter, have you considered separating the data by schema?

Comment: @bma really not interested in replication of non-essential.  Its more about keeping the non-essential out of the app for performance, but then not creating some crazy cross database environment where some data is in A and some is in B .. is that what you mean by a separate schema?